# SQL Server with RegExp

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for a T-SQL query with regular expression to select records with today's date from sample data as below:

Sample data format:

```
[DAILY|MASTER|SUPER]-Integer-Date(yyyymmdd)

DAILY-60-20151216
DAILY-61-20151217
SUPER-62-20151218
DAILY-63-20151219
MASTER-64-20151220
DAILY-65-20151221
SUPER-66-20151222
DAILY-67-20151222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for this, just the `right()` function:

```
where cast(right(data, 8) as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```